# Return Flux JsonObject from N1QL query output

Tags: java, couchbase, sql++

I am trying to execute a N1QL query using the @Query annotation as below:

```
@Query(“SELECT META().id as __id, META().cas as __cas, user_id, firstname, lastname, city, phonenumber, email, postalcode FROM userData where user_id= $1”)
Flux <JsonObject> findByUserId(String user_id);
}
```

I want to retrieve the data into  JsonObject and return this flux object back to the controller. But this always gives null. If I use a POJO class for example `Flux<User>` then I do get the data.

Is there something missing or is there another method to return data into JsonObject.
Thanks.